# How to get Average Time Ping with PHP?

Tags: php

I use this code to get Time Ping :

```
<?php
$address = 'stackoverflow.com';
$ping = system("ping $address");
echo '<pre>';
echo $ping;
?>
```

And the output is :

> Pinging stackoverflow.com [104.16.35.249] with 32 bytes of data:
>  Reply
>   from 104.16.35.249: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57 
> Reply from
>   104.16.35.249: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=57
>  Reply from 104.16.35.249: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57 
> Reply from 104.16.35.249: bytes=32 time=15ms
>   TTL=57 
> Ping statistics for 104.16.35.249:
>  Packets: Sent = 4, Received
>   = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
>  Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: 
> Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 16ms, Average = 15ms
>       
>  Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 16ms, Average = 15ms

But, I just want to get Average Time Ping, how to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `exec()` function

```
$address = 'stackoverflow.com';
$ping = exec("ping $address");
$pingTime = explode(',',trim($ping));
echo $pingTime[2];
$time = explode("=",trim($pingTime[2]));
echo $time[1];
```

Comment: wow it works. The output is : "Average = 15ms " . Is it possible to show only the number and ms ?

Comment: the output is "Average = 15ms 15ms "

Comment: You need to remove this line `echo $pingTime[2];`